# MySQL Date Range Multi Column Count and Group By Select Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a query I have been working on for a while but I cannot seem to get it down. The other answers on here work well for counting an amount with a certain date range then grouping by the date to get the count. However I need to have two columns counted and grouped by date.

For example here is the query I have tried to get to work:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) arrived, DATE(arrived) date, 'arrived' AS source
FROM products 
WHERE arrived BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31'
GROUP BY DATE(date)
ORDER BY date ASC)

UNION ALL 

(SELECT COUNT(*) released, DATE(released) date, 'released' AS source
FROM products 
WHERE released BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31'
GROUP BY DATE(date)
ORDER BY date ASC)
```

However this returns the following:

```
arrived  date       source
3        2016-01-12  arrived
2        2016-01-28  arrived
1        2016-01-29  arrived
1        2016-01-05  released
```

What I am requiring is something like this:

```
date           arrived   released   
2016-01-05     0         1
2016-01-12     3         0
2016-01-28     2         0
2016-01-29     1         0
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply *conditional aggregation* to a derived table obtained by a `UNION ALL` operation for 'arrived' and 'released' dates:

```
SELECT `date`, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'arrived' THEN 1 END) AS arrived,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'released' THEN 1 END) AS released
FROM (
  SELECT arrived AS `date`, 'arrived' as type
  FROM products
  WHERE arrived BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT released AS `date`, 'released' as type
  FROM products
  WHERE released BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31') AS t
GROUP BY `date`
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b90eb/1)

Comment: Thank you, that works except for one thing, it will pull the arrived date for something that was released that day. For example, on 2016-01-05 when I had 1 item released it will show 1 item released and 0 items arrived, just as I wanted. However for that item that was released it is showing its arrival date (2015-10-04) instead of its release date (2016-01-05). This is of course because you put DATE(arrived) date, which will grab the arrival date. Is there any way it could be DATE(arrived) OR DATE(released) so it grabs the correct date?

Comment: @Ethan Yes, you are right. I have misread the schema of your table. Let me restructure the query to suit the real schema of your table.